# Ruby on Rails 4 CSV File recursive loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am having a very strange problem with loading a CSV file that is driving my absolutely crazy and doesn't make any sense to me!  I am loading a CSV file into my database with the following code:

```
  CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('public','uploads', '0', csv_file.file_name), :headers => true, :header_converters => lambda { |h| h.try(:downcase)}) do |row|
      Exclusion.create!(row.to_hash)
  end
```

I have a file with 14,808 entries. If I try to load the file at once, for some reason it adds all 14,808 entries into the database as expected, but then starts over again from entry 1.  It continues to do this in a recursive manner until I stop the server or it crashes. If I break the file down into two files, the individual files get added to the database as expected.  I thought it may be a problem with the number of records, but I was able to load a csv file with about 100,000 records without this problem.  I am very baffled as to why this is occurring.  Oddly, if I comment out the create statement and just put a counter there, it stops at 14,808.  Also, if I create a view that prints each row.to_hash, it stops at 14,808.  I can't figure out what about saving it into the database would cause it to continue to repeat itself?  I am using SQLite3, but again, I dont have a problem with a CSV file with 100,000 records.

**Update**:

Going through the log, it looks like the CSV file is loaded properly and all records are added to the database.  Ruby even redirects to the proper url afterwards, but then seems to receive the "load file" request again.  Since my screen has already timed out waiting for the server to process the CSV file, could that be causing an error and leading to either a duplicate request to load the file or the server thinking it hasn't processed the request and starting over?

Comment: I am still trying to figure this problem out.  Is there a reason why RoR wouldn't recognize that it has reached the end of a csv file and would go back to the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers sometimes repeat requests. If you have a catch-all route that goes to one action (the one that loads CSV file) then it could also be triggered by the browsers requesting favicon.ico.

However, I'd ask, why are you using a web request for this? Does csv_file come from the user? If not (i.e. if you already have the CSV file you want to load) I'd recommend putting this in a [Rake](http://docs.seattlerb.org/rake/) task and just running it manually.

Comment: Thank you Frankpinto!  The action for loading the CSV file is separate.  It is odd why it keeps reloading.  I guess I will have to create a worker thread to load the file since it does get initiated from users as well, but the rake task worked as a good temp fix!